# Minecraft File Comparison script

Tags: file, comparison, minecraft

I would like create a batch file that will do a comparison between the minecraft mods folder on a client PC and an FTP site with all the current mods I have on my server.  During the comparison, if something is found that is different, I want the script to be able to delete old mods and download the updated mod.  I would need to do the same thing for the config folder/files.  At the end of the script, I would like it to start minecraft (which is really the easy part).

I have looked into some file comparison scripts, but I'm not entirely sure I know how to get it to do what I'm asking, especially the file download/delete part.  I tried to find a thread with some info but I can't find anything specific to what I'm trying to do.

EDIT:
Sorry. i forgot to include my code.

I borrowed a script that was simply checking one folder and comparing another but it would only report the file missing. So I attempted to adjust it to what I'm trying to do. I'll post the script I borrowed first:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "folderA=D:\NONMEM7.3beta7.0"
set "folderB=D:\NONMEM7.3beta7.0Renamed"
for %%a in ("%folderA%\*.f90") do if not exist "%folderB%\%%~na_recoded%%~xa" echo %%~na_recoded%%~xa not found in %folderB%.
for %%a in ("%folderB%\*.f90") do for /f "delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do if not exist "%folderA%\%%~b%%~xa" echo %%~b%%~xa not found in %folderA%.
```

And here is the code I tried to adjust. Unfortunately, I don't quite know how to use the variables. I'm trying to figure them out but I'm somewhat new to this.

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "Mods=%appdata%\.minecraft\mods"
set "ServerMods=ftp:\\<serverIP>\mods"
For %%a in ("%ServerMods%\*.jar") do if not exist "%Mods\*<not sure how to specify individual files>.jar" copy /y ServerMods\<file>.jar Mods
```

Thanks

Comment: Post what you've written so far.

Comment: Sorry. i forgot to include that. I have added it to the initial post.

Comment: Look into [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).